# How to add animation to grid in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a grid control .On button click this grid  will be visible.In the back end code   I added child element to the grid in the button click .I want this grid to be loaded in specific pattern with certain animation. Please suggest a solution

```
<Grid x:Name="menuholder" Height="Auto" Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
      Grid.RowSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,15,0">
</Grid>
```

In Back end :

```
MenuUserControl menu = new MenuUserControl();
menu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
menu.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
menu.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
menu.Width = 200;
menuholder.Children.Add(menu);
menuholder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
isMenuVisible = false;
Canvas.SetZIndex(menu, 2);
```

Comment: You might be animate what you want, but you didn't provide any details of what you've tried or the desired outcome. Have you looked at Storyboards?

Comment: I looked at story board but unable to get my requirement.i.e,My grid most come from right top corner and must visible at its place.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you better describe the animation you're trying to achieve? If you can't do it with a storyboard, I'd suspect then you'd need to do it manually, with timers (which I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: If you're trying to animate the height of an auto sized control, you can't. You'll need to either decide you will try a different effect or use something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Storyboard for the Grid

Sample

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid x:Name="grdAnimated" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="100" Width="200">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="grdStoryBoard">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grdAnimated">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="900"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateY="900" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
   </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

In your xaml.cs code

Begin the Storyborad on your button action like:

```
grdStoryBoard.Begin();
```

You can change your animation type accordingly
Refer  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx

Storyboard can be well created with the help of Blend
Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129478.aspx

Comment: I was successfull in loading the grid with animation by above solution i want to unload it or remove the child control with certain animation what extra code i should  add